# What is the minimum and maximum dps for each character?

Tags: overwatch

I want to compare the minimum and maximum dps of all Overwatch characters with each other. I know that for example tracer has a whooping 240 dps, while Genji only deals 84 dps. That knight guy is like 75 dps.

For example, documents would say how many pellets per second or how many shuriken per seconds.

Then we got to do some math

Comment: What do you mean "min dps"? That's 0 for all characters.

Comment: normal hit say you hit but far away

Comment: Wut?  Genji deals significantly more than 84dps.  Are you not comboing your attacks?

Answer (score 4):

Source - http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Heroes

Let's go.

First off, a headshot deals *2 damage, so if you want max DPS, factor that into your calculation. Ults have been excluded. Damage falloff has been excluded from my calculations, but someone has compiled it, available at the bottom of the answer. Aside from Genji, abilities have been discounted.

**Maximums**

*Offence*

**Genji**: 28 (Damage) * 3 (ROF) *2 = 168 (Headshot) + 50 (Swiftstrike) = 218

**Mcree**:  6.9 rounds per second * 45(Fan the hammer) * 2 (Headshots, impossible to pull off with the accuracy of Fan the hammer, but here you go) = 310.5

**Pharah**: 120 Damage on bodyshot

**Reaper**: 20 (pellets in each shot) * 7 (Pellet max damage) * 2 (Headshot) * 2 (rate of fire of 2 shots a second)  = 560

**Soldier 76**: 17 (Max damage) * 10 (ROF of 10 shots per second) = 170 * 2 (headshots) = 340

**Tracer**: 6 (Damage per round) * 40 (Rounds per second) * 2 (Headshot) =  480

*Defense*

**Bastion**: 15 (Damage) * 35 (Rounds per second) * 2 (Headshot) = 1050

**Hanzo**: 125 (Damage) * 2 (Headshot) = 250

**Junkrat**: 120 (Damage) * 1.66 (ROF) = 199.2

**Mei**: (Right Click) 75 (Damage) * 1.8 (ROF) * 2 (Headshot) = 270

**Torbjörn**: (Right Click)  =  15 (Damage Per pellet) * 10 (Pellets) * 1.33 (ROF) * 2 (Headshot) = 399

**Widowmaker**: 120 (Damage)  * 2.5 (Widow's special Headshot modifier) = 300

*Tanks*

**D.va** = 3 (Damage) * 8 (Pellets) * 7 (ROF) * 2 (Headshot) = 336

**Reinhardt**: 75 (Damage) * 1(ROF) = 75

**Roadhog**: 9 (Damage per pellet) * 25 (Pellets per shot) * 2 (Headshot)  = 450

**Winston**: 3 (Damage per round) *  20 (Rounds per second) = 60

**Zarya**: 95 (DPS Standard) * 2 (100% bonus from fully charged) = 190

*Supports*

**Ana**: 80 (Damage) * 1.2 (ROF) = 96

**Lúcio**: 16 (Damage) * 4 (Projectiles) * 2 (Headshot) = 128

**Mercy**: 20 (Damage) * 5 (ROF) * 2 (Headshot) = 200

**Symmetra**: 120 (Max DPS on Left-click lockon after 2 seconds)

**Zenyatta** 40 (Damage) * 2.5 (ROF) * 2 (Headshot) = 240

**Minimums**
If you're asking for damage falloff, research has been done here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4oq5ee/by_the_numbers_damage_falloff/

Comment: I assume "right-click" is alternate fire, which would be the shotgun for Torbjorn.

Comment: ^ Yes it is, sorry. Kind of used to PC terminology.

Comment: You're not the only one writing Overwatch posts like it's PC exclusive.

Comment: Chill dude, I wrote it from memory, I'm not trying to act superior or anything. But the way Blizzard support consoles, it might as well be exclusive.

Comment: I feel pretty chill. There's something less than perfect in your question, so I pointed it out to help you to improve it. The intention is to be helpful. It's a common theme among a lot of these questions, so I was saying there's no need to be sorry because it's a common mistake. Fixing is better than being sorry. If you have a negative reaction to people pointing out minor flaws in your posts so you can improve them, you're going to have a bad time on Stack Exchange.